# How to handle @select in Play! Framework

Tags: java, forms, playframework, combobox

I'm trying to fill a combo using the helper @select of Play! in a form, but searching a lot, I not found what I exactly need.

I want something like this:

```
@select(
    filmeForm("Director"),
    options(Seq(aListOfDirectors))
)
```

This is a form of register of movies, that get Foreign key of a Director.
I need list the directors names, and when I send the form, I need to get the ID of selected director.

If this way is not possible, some similar way will be useful.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get the directors ID bound to the form. You can make the sequence a sequence of tuples: Seq((directorID -> directorName)) and populate the value attribute of the select with the directorID...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML `select` tag can have a set of `option` tags like the following:

```
<select id="directors-select" name="director">
    <option value="steven-spilberg">Steven Spilberg</option>
    <option value="stanley-kubric">Stanley Kubric</option>
</select>
```

So, to proper populate `select`'s `option`s, Play `@select` helper requires that the `Seq` contains a tuple `(String, String)`, which will contains both the `value` attribute and also the "label" presented to the user. In other words, `options` parameter needs to be a `Seq[(String, String)]`. Here is the example [given at the docs](http://localhost:9000/@documentation/api/scala/views/html/helper/select$.html):

```
@select(
  field = myForm("mySelect"),
  options = Seq(
    "Foo" -> "foo text",
    "Bar" -> "bar text",
    "Baz" -> "baz text"
   ),
  '_default -> "Choose One",
  '_disabled -> Seq("FooKey", "BazKey")
  'cust_att_name -> "cust_att_value"
)
```

So, your `aListOfDirectors` needs to contains a `(String, String)` tuple. But it is actually pretty simple to solve this, just change your code to:

```
@select(
    field = filmeForm("Director"),
    options = aListOfDirectors.map(director => director.id.toString -> director.name)
)
```

Here, I'm considering that `aListOfDirectors` is a `Seq[Director]`.

#### Where is it documented?

Play [documentation for (Java) forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaFormHelpers#Rendering-an-<input>-element) states that "there are several input helpers in the `views.html.helper` package." After that, I just looked up at the [play scaladocs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#package) and then navigate to [`views.html.helper`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.package) package. There you can find the [docs for `@select`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.select$).

I know that when people says "read the docs" that sometimes sounds harsh, but it is a good advice considering that framework/software/lib developers (who **really knows** the framework/software/lib) spent their time to explain how to use the framework/software/lib, we for sure can spend some time reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks, it's works fine. Where did you found this information, 
specifically how to populate the options using that way? I do not found this information in documentation of play.

Comment: See the edit I've made at the end of the answer. Also, please, consider mark it as the answer for your question.